# Groovy / Hibernate / @Transaction returns No Session found for current thread

Tags: hibernate, spring, groovy, spring-transactions

I have a Spring/JPA/Groovy/Hibernate stack, (note: **not grails**), and I'm finding that I'm getting a `No session found for current thread` when trying to perform some `@Transactional` work on startup.

I have a controller class that, upon `@PostConstruct`, invokes a `@Transactional` method on another class which tries to populate the database with some sample data to be used in a simulation.

Here's the `controller` class:

```
@Component
public class SimulationController {

    private TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
    @Autowired
    private IPublisher publisher;

    @PostConstruct
    public void intialize()
    {
        this.transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus arg0) {
                racePublisher.populateData();
            }
        });
    }
    //  Also tried, with no success:    
    //  @PostConstruct
    //  public void initialize()
    //  {
    //      publisher.populateData();
    //  }
}
```

As you can see, I've moved away from a pure `@Transactional` approach in the `@PostConstruct` for reasons discussed [here](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?58337-No-transaction-in-transactional-service-called-from-PostConstruct).

My `IPublisher` is a groovy class, as follows:

```
@Component
class Publisher implements IPublisher {

@Autowired
IStockDAO stockDAO

void populateData()
{
    createStock()
}
@Transactional
void createStock()
{
    def list = [new Stock(ticker: "ADBE", name: "Adobe"),
                new Stock(ticker: "MSFT", venueCode: "Microsoft")]
    list.each { stockDAO.create it }
}
```

Which is an implementation of:

```
public interface IPublisher {

    public void populateData();
    public void createStock();
}
```

Note, I've also tried marking `populateData()` as `@Transactional`, with no effect.

In my Spring context class, I'm defining `<tx:annotation-driven/>`.

As far as I can tell, I've done everything correctly.  However, I can't seem to get this to work.

What else is required?

**Updated:**
Here are the beans setting up my dataAccess related beans:

```
<beans>
<bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://${database.host}:${database.port}/${database.name}" />
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
        <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxActive" value="50" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <list>
                <value>com.mangofactory.concorde</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
                </prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop><!--  use create for full drop/create -->
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.statement_cache.size">0</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <beans>
```

Comment: How is your transactionManager defined?

Comment: @mrembisz I've added the declarations to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `HibernateTransactionManager` instead of `DataSourceTransactionManager`.

Comment: @mrembisz +1 for noticing the simple thing :)

Answer (score 0):

There are basic issues with the code. The transactional boundary starts in the createStock method of the Publisher class and ends there. It does not propagate to your controller . Use the DB query calls inside a transaction . i.e , inside a method which has the Transactional annotation. Else it would never work .

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're saying here.  I am using DB query calls inside a transaction - the call to `create` is wrapped inside a `@Transactional` block

Comment: @MartyPitt The transaction template codes are outside the transaction boundary . It will not work in the intialize() method . It'll work in a method with the transactional annotation .

Comment: @AravindA `transactionTemplate.execute()` is api equivalent of `@Transactional`. This code should work IMO.